# DB Error: unknown error when accessing any report menu after upgrade to 5.10.0

Tags: upgrade

I have just updated CiviCRM under Joomla! from 4.7.6 to 5.10.0. The upgrade went well, with no issues. I have following the instructions on the page "Upgrading CiviCRM for Joomla". I can use CiviCRM except whenever i access any report menu i get :

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
>
> DB Error: unknown error

Items on here say to look in the ConfigAndLog file which i think for Joomla should be at 
administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm but i do not see it there.

Anyone have any suggestions on how this can be resolved?

thanks
Dave

Comment: should just add Joomla! is v3.6.5 and running on php5.6. Once the CiviCRM upgrade is successful and i have tested Joomla! upgrade to latest i will replicate updates in the  production site and move to php v7.2

Comment: Look in media/civicrm for the log file.

Comment: thanks - found it. Contents dont mean much to me but look like they give a lead, can anyone suggest what is wrong and how to fix it? Here is as much as SE will allow me to post $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -19
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_menu (domain_id , path , title , access_callback , access_arguments , page_callback , breadcrumb , is_ssl , we ... Unknown column 'module_data' in 'field list']

Comment: You can edit your original question to post more of the log.

Comment: Even though you said the upgrade went well it sounds like some database columns didn't get added. This one specifically: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20927

Comment: thanks - cant see in the link that there is anything documented to resolve this. Does it mean i will have to go to my backup and start over? If so is there anything i can do to either prevent it happening again or to identify why it doesnt work? Sorry for all the questions but this is my first CiviCRM upgrade

Comment: You could manually add the module_data column but it's likely something else went wrong, so starting over might be best. You could try an intermediate upgrade to 4.7.24 first, since that's where the issue says the column was added. Looking at the code though it was 4.7.25. Could try both.

Answer (score 2):

On the Finish page of the CiviCRM 5.10.1 and 5.10.4 component installation, there is a little link called "Utility for Updating the Database structure" or something similar. Up til running that little link, we received the "DB Error: Field missing" error when running some reports.